# Install OpenCV via pip on Python 3.5 64-bit

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, 64-bit, pip

I tried to install OpenCV, and I couldn't find any suitable pip packages for it. I decided to look online for official documentation on how to install it, and found [this](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_windows/py_setup_in_windows.html#install-opencv-python-in-windows). Unfortunately, not only does this documentation only give support for versions using python 2.7, it also says to install OpenCV manually by downloading it from sourceforge rather than using a package manager like pip.

I want to know if there's a better or more official way of installing OpenCV in python 3.5, or failing that, a package in pip I should install instead.

Comment: The difficulty to make it work with pip lays in the number of C header files that need to be referenced. Nevertheless, it would be great to have a straightforward way to install this. Maybe, pip and some environmental vars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What OS are you on? If it's Windows have a look at

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv

To properly install the available wheels make sure you have pip version 8 installed.