# cant install cv2 in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, pip

I am using a book called Hello World to learn Python. I used the installer at "http://helloworldbookblog.com/downloads/", which installs python 2.7, among other things. The lesson I'm on now has a sample program that I'm supposed to look at, but unfortunately, when I try to run it, it throws this error

> no module named cv2

I've tried for days, but I just can't seem to figure out how to install `cv2`. Is there a simple way that I'm missing?

For some reason, the installer didn't include pip, and I can't figure out how to install that either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install OpenCV via pip on Python 3.5 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37736760/install-opencv-via-pip-on-python-3-5-64-bit)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bopencv%5D+%5Bpip%5D+install

Answer (score 0):

Install OpenCV (https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/) to access the module cv2. If python is correctly installed, https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/install-pip-windows/ gives you steps to install pip. Hope this helped